# Limit of $\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)^n $

Tags: limits, exponential-function

> Compute$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)^n $$

I dont know how to do it without using continuity of exponential function

I mean I cannot do this:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}a_n =a  \wedge  \lim_{x\to\infty}b_n =b\Rightarrow  \lim_{x\to\infty}{a_n}^{b_n} =a^b$$

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ rather than $\lim_{x\to\infty}$?

Comment: Yea, sorry my bad

Comment: $$1\leqslant1+\frac2{n^2}\leqslant e^{2/n^2}\implies1\leqslant\left(1+\frac2{n^2}\right)^n\leqslant e^{2/n}\to1$$

Comment: "I dont know how to do it without using (the) continuity of (the) exponential function" What do you call "using (the) continuity of (the) exponential function" here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Bernoulli:

$$\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)^n= \frac{1}{\left(\frac{n^2}{n^2+2}\right)^n}= \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{2}{n^2+2}\right)^n}$$

And by Bernoulli
$$\left(1-\frac{2}{n^2+2}\right)^n \geq 1-\frac{2n}{n^2+2}=\frac{n^2-2n+2}{n^2+2}$$

Therefore
$$1 \leq \left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)^n \leq \frac{n^2+2}{n^2-2n+2}$$

Comment: I'm not sure how well-known "Bernoulli" is in this context.  For completeness, then, "Bernoulli" refers to Bernoulli's inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality), which is the fact that $(1+x)^r \ge 1+rx$, for positive integer $r$ and real $x$ with $x \ge -1$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the expression equals $[(1+2/n^2)^{n^2}]^{1/n}.$

Comment: I have no idea how it would help.

Comment: Except you meant this $[(1+2/n^2)^{n^2/2}]^{2/n}$ but as I said I can't do like that

Comment: @TheMeff the inner expression of the root have value less than $10$, i.e. $$\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}<10,\forall n\in\Bbb N$$

Comment: Ok, now I got it, Thanks :)

Comment: I know that this kind of trick is routinely suggested on the site as if it was elementary and that it is regularly upvoted and chosen as *the* canonical approach but it always surprises me that users can "swallow" the assertion that $$\lim x_n= x\implies \lim(x_n)^{2/n}=\lim x^{2/n}=1$$ as if it was trivial that $$\lim x_n=x\ \&\lim f_n(x)=\ell\implies\lim f_n(x_n)=\ell$$ And suddenly the implication does not seem so obvious, does it?

Comment: @Did I know, i said that before, i can't use it because it's not so obvious. But what I can is $\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{n^2}{2}*2/n}<10^{2/n}$ cant't I?

Comment: @TheMeff You can, and even, $(1+1/x)^x\leqslant e$ for every $x>0$.

Comment: @Did I didn't make that assertion. It's a hint, not a full solution. The term in brackets is very close to $e^2$ for large $n$ and now one can gut-guess the answer. The final details are up to the reader.

Comment: Ouch! Sorry but this is a terribly wrong argument. "Hint" should not be used to signal that one uses misleading approaches, omitting the justifications of some delicate steps. In the present case, you are sending the OP on a line of reasoning they probably cannot complete rigorously. Worse, they explicitely mentioned they had problems with the $a_n^{b_n}\to a^b$ approach...

Comment: Ouch yourself, there is no misleading approach. Geez, this is how you spend your time today?

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the limit of the *function* (as opposed to sequence)
$$
f(x)=\left(1+\frac{2}{x^2}\right)^{\!x}
$$
or, better yet, the limit of its (natural) logarithm:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{2}{x^2}\right)^{\!x}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\log\left(1+\frac{2}{x^2}\right)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\log(1+2t^2)}{t}
$$
after the substitution $x=1/t$.

This is the derivative at $0$ of $g(t)=\log(1+2t^2)$ and
$$
g'(t)=\frac{4t}{1+2t^2}
$$
so $g'(0)=0$. Hence
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\log f(x)=0
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=e^0=1
$$
If the limit of the function exists, it is the same as the limit of the sequence.

Comment: If one looks carefully at your answer, one sees you did not actually prove that $g'(0)=0$, only that $g'(t)\to0$ when $t\to0$ -- which is not the result one needs.

Comment: @Did Sorry? I'm under the impression that $g$ is a $C^\infty$ function. Don't you trust the formulas for the derivatives of the elementary functions?

Comment: What? If you intend to reply to my comment, please read what I actually wrote in said comment. Another hint: rather amazingly, my comment addresses what is written in your question, not the existence or inexistence of other arguments I could provide myself to write down a complete proof.

Comment: @Did Nowhere I say nor use that $\lim_{t\to0}g'(t)=0$. Do you agree that $g'(0)=\lim\limits_{t\to0}\frac{g(t)-g(0)}{t-0}=\lim\limits_{t\to0}\frac{\log(1+2t^2)}{t}$? Do you agree that ***for every*** $t$, $g'(t)=4t/(1+2t^2)$?

Comment: Upon rereading, you are right. I somewhat misread what you wrote, and saw problems where there is none. Sorry about the noise (and +1 for your answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just another way.

Consider $$A=\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)^n\implies \log(A)=n\log\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)$$ Now, since $n$ is large, use Taylor series a round $x=0$ $$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)\implies \log\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)=\frac{2}{n^2}-\frac{2}{n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right)$$ $$\log(A)=n\log\left(1+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)=\frac{2}{n}-\frac{2}{n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ Now, using $A=e^{\log(A)}$ an Taylor again $$A=1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}-\frac{2}{3 n^3}-\frac{10}{3
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

All of the above was done for infinitely large values of $n$. However, it gives "good" results far even small values of $n$. For example, using $n=10$, the exact resulut would be $$A=\left(1+\frac{1}{50}\right)^{10}=\frac{119042423827613001}{97656250000000000}\approx 1.21899$$ while the approximation would lead to $\frac{1219}{1000}=1.21900$.